# Why is this piece of simple code not working

Tags: python

I have errors with this program. Can you help me explain what is going on because the system seems to confuse my variables as strings. I have tried changing the variables but it always seems to stop working.

```
# Area of rectangle
a = input("What is the length of side a in centimeters")
b = input("What is the length of side b in centimeters")
area = a * b
print(area)
```

It gives me this response

```
line 5, in <module>
    area = a * b
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'
```

Given my amateur coding status, all I take from this is that its trying to multiply strings where there are no strings.

Comment: You can't multiply an `str` by another `str` or by a `float` or by a `byte`. You can only multiply an `str` by an `int`.

Comment: Man, I don't understand why teachers make you use something like Pycharm when you are learning to code.  I can totally understand an IDE for learning a language like Java, C++ etc, but if you are learning *Python* sometimes I think text-editor/terminal is a good combination when you are beginning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The previous answers are correct in that the simple fix is to cast the input to an `int` value. However, this error is a little mysterious:

> TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'

and deserves to be explained.

What's happening here is that python understands a string to be a sequence of characters. This is true even of a single character, eg `'a'` or of no characters, eg `''` - you don't generally make use of the underlying character type in python.

And it turns out that in python you can multiply a sequence - a list or a tuple or some such - by a numeric value `n` to repeat that sequence n times:

```
>>> [1, 2, 3] * 5
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```

and so you can do this with strings:

```
>>> "abc" * 3
'abcabcabc'
```

but you can't multiply a sequence by another sequence:

```
>>> [1, 2, 3] * ['a', 'b', 'c']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'list'
```

and as expected we get the same error when trying to multiply a string by a string:

```
>>> "abc" * "def"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'
```

even if both strings look like numbers:

```
>>> "6" * "10"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'
```

I hope this helps you understand not just how to fix the error, but what the error was to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast the input to an int/float.

`input` returns a string so you need to cast it like this:

```
int(a) * int(b)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
# Area of rectangle
a = input("What is the length of side a in centimeters")
b = input("What is the length of side b in centimeters")
#convert input to int.
area = int(a) * int(b)
print(area)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

`input()` reads the given number as a string. You have to convert into a number before doing any arithmetic calculations

```
a = int(input("What is the length of side a in centimeters"))
b = int(input("What is the length of side b in centimeters"))
area = a * b
print(area)
```

OR

```
a = input("What is the length of side a in centimeters")
b = input("What is the length of side b in centimeters")
area = int(a) * int(b)
print(area)
```

**Note:**
You can simplify the code(if you want):

```
 a = int(input("What is the length of side a in centimeters"))
 b = int(input("What is the length of side b in centimeters"))
 print(a*b)
```